# Como saber que parametro ingreso en un update en procedimiento almacenado oracle

Tags: sql, oracle-11g

Hola tengo un Stored Procedure y quiero saber como saber que dato ingreso para el update, soy nuevo en Sql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE hola(opcion in varchar2,rut in varchar2
,comuna in varchar2 default null,razon in varchar2 default null
,giros in varchar2 default null,dir in varchar2 default null,telefono in varchar2 default null) as
begin 
if opcion = 'insert' then 
insert into Cliente values(rut,comuna,razon,giros,dir,telefono);
commit;
elsif opcion = 'update' then
update Cliente set 
cod_comuna=comuna,
razon_social=razon,
giro=giros,
direccion=dir,
fono=telefono
where rut_cliente=rut;
commit;
elsif opcion = 'delete' then
delete from Cliente where rut_cliente=rut;
commit;
end if;
end;
/
```

Por ejemplo saber como se si ingreso razon o ingreso giro, en caso de

```
hola(update,1-1,avenida hola)
```

como puedo lograr que el procedimiento logre saber que el avenida hola sea una direccion y no la inserte en razon, esa es mi duda, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En las variables de entrada estas especificando ese campo, dentro de las variables de entrada debes especificar los campos correspondientes. Para que el procedimiento lo inserte donde tu quieres debes indicar donde se va insertar. Para que se actualice en dirección seria de esta manera.

> --   opcion  rut  comuna razon   giro     dir
>
> > hola(update, 1-1,  null,  null,  null,  avenida hola)

Y en tu ejemplo no lo actualizas ni en razon sino en comuna.
La manera en que ingresas los valores de entrada es como se van a actualizar en tu BD y  en razón a como ingresas los valores es como los guarda el procedimiento.